# How can I execute shell command from Kiosked chromium?

Tags: bash, command-line, chrome

I need to find a way to execute a bash script to throw up a 'dialog' to the user while in full screen Kiosk mode in chromium.

EDIT: To clarify with 'dialog' I mean the simple bash gui you can make with the command 'dialog'.

I'm running chromium in just the raw CLI environment for security reasons. (my son is getting better at hacking my setups)
Im using 'startx' to launch chromium.

There's no keyboard or mouse connected just a joystick but I'm running a program in the background so that in theory I can trigger single key input through a special joystick hotkey.

So far I haven't been able to trigger and scripts while in Kiosk mode.

I don't know if I need to somehow suspend and minimize chromium to do this?

I have played with 'screen' a bit to possibly run my 'dialog' script on a different 'screen'.

Iv'e also tried 'bind' but no luck so far with that either.

But the first problem is how can I run a command from the CLI run kiosked chromium?

Cheers!

Comment: you could use javascript to generate the dialog

Comment: use js to make a dialog prompt maybe

Comment: @jsotola -- oof sniped

Comment: Do you mean to run from within the browser somehow?

I need to be able run bash scripts from the dialog I throw up. As I'm putting Audio device selection, volume control and other similar things there.